# How to remove all nodes from selected ranges

Tags: javascript, range, selection

For example, I have such text:

```
Some test <span> in span1</span> sss <span>in span2</span> end of text.
```

when I select " test in span1 sss in spa" I want to just delete parent spans of selected ranges and create new range 
that will contain my selected text.

```
Some<span> test in span1 sss in spa</span>n2 end of text.
```

I'm using `window.getSelection()`,range,nodes

Please help!

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with the `deleteContents()`, `toString()` and `insertNode()` methods of a range obtained from the selection.

The following will work in all major browsers except IE <= 8. You'll need a different approach for those browsers, which I can outline if you need it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HUm2K/

Code:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
    var selectedTextNode = document.createTextNode( range.toString() );
    newSpan.appendChild(selectedTextNode);
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(newSpan);
    range.selectNode(newSpan);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}
```

Comment: deleteContents functions results in empty nodes. How can I remove the node also?

Comment: @user2356198: The simplest solution would be to remove the empty elements after the `range.insertNode(newSpan);` line. You could use `getElementsByTagName("*")` with `hasChildNodes()` to find the empty elements.

Comment: Initially it was that: `<p>content 1</p><p>content 2</p><p>content 3</p><p>remaining content>`. I merged the first 3 p's, and result: `<p></p><p>content 1<br>content 2<br>content 3</p><p>remaining content</p>`. Just I want to delete empt p nodes. How can I do that Tim?

Comment: Tim, why do you add `range.selectNode(newSpan); sel.removeAllRanges(); sel.addRange(range);`. Is it a must?

Comment: @user2356198: In some browsers changing the selected range changes the selection itself (e.g. Firefox) and in others it does nothing (e.g. Chrome). I think the spec doesn't say one way or another what should happen. Example: http://output.jsbin.com/zuxewazifa